# Redirect a specific folder to a virtual folder using .Htaccess (make it look like a subdomain)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

So here's my directory structure:

```
|--public_html Dir
|--index.php File
|--search.php File
|----assets/ Dir
|----acp/ Dir
|------assets/ Dir
```

What I need is a .htaccess way of doing the following:

- Redirect http://example.com/ --> http://club.example.com/ (Where club
  is not a sub directory, it doesn't exist on the server)
- Redirect all pages the same way: e.g. http://club.example.com/search.php
- Redirect the `/acp/` directory and it's files like this: http://club.example.com/acp/post.php
- Redirect the `/public_html/assets/` directory too but my javascript files, css files and images are there. I should be able to access them like this: http://club.example.com/assets/theme/reset.css , etc.
- The same goes for `/acp/assets/` directory. It contains the styling and scripting for the admin page so I need to access files inside it like this: http://club.example.com/acp/assets/scripts/menu.js

Comment: Do you have root access or access to apache config?

Comment: No, I'm on a shared hosting.

Comment: Why not simply create the club addon domain and just use the subdomain?

Comment: Well... I'll have to google the .htaccess code to redirect main to sub domain. But I've not used sub domains before - I like to avoid them if I can use my main domain :/ there has to be a way to rewrite like this. I've seen such code some time ago making a folder appear before the domain and separate them with a dot...

Comment: That doesn't really make since. You want the URL to display as club.example.com so what are you trying to avoid? A subdomain works exactly the same way as any other domain. ie. www.example.com is a subdomain actually. people are just used to see `www` in front but it is a subdomain. It's just how you setup the alias. Its very simple to redirect to subdomain also. Rewrites/.htaccess cause a slight performance hit so why use it if you really don't need it.

Comment: I know about the `www`. But seeing there's no other way to do this I guess I'll just use a subdomain.

Comment: Subdomains don't have to point to a subdirectory of `public_html`, they can just point straight to the same directory, then do your domain redirect in your `.htaccess`. There's no point hiding folders above the web root if you're just going to rewrite to them, you may as well just put them in the place your URLs think they are.